# Strange client's address returned throug accept(..) function

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I'm a socket programming newbie. Here's a snippet:

```
struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;

...

client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
client_socket = accept( server_socket,
    (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_size );

...

result = inet_ntop( AF_INET,
    &((struct sockaddr_in *)&client_addr)->sin_addr,
    client_addr_str, sizeof(client_addr_str) );
```

I'm working as a server. Whenever the client connects the address I get is 0.0.0.0 regardless from the host. Can anybody explain, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `client_addr.ss_family` - it may be returning an `AF_INET6` family address.

Comment: Yes, that was right. I've fixed the problem. Yet another one arouse. I use getaddrinfo function with AI_PASSIVE in hints.
The address I later bind my socket to is :: . Is it okay?

Comment: Yes, that's fine (as long as the socket is still an `AF_INET6` one).

Answer (score 0):

Can you show a bit more code...what IP address/service are you trying to connect to?

The clue is in the IP address itself, 0.0.0.0, commonly a situation where a network interface has no IP address assigned, possibly looking for a DHCP server to renew/accept a DHCP lease from somewhere..

I am shooting myself in the foot as you have not provided enough information and hence would be deemed unfair to do so and get downvoted as a result as this answer does not satisfy your question!!

Comment: He's not connecting *to* anything; he's acting as a server and accepting connections.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - what's the declaration of `client_addr_str`? If it's `char*` then `sizeof(client_addr_str)` would return size of pointer (4 or 8, depending on 32- or 64-bit platform.) Try the following:

```
char client_addr_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
if ( inet_ntop( AF_INET,
    &((struct sockaddr_in *)&client_addr)->sin_addr,
    client_addr_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN ) == NULL )
{
    /* complain */
}
```